# How to select the date column which has different date formats in mysql?

Tags: mysql

my table has date column of varchar datatype it accept different date formats(dd-mm-yy,mm-dd-yy,yy-mm-dd),how can i select the records of this table.

> ### Name |  Date
>
> John  |    2014-01-01
>
> Kane |   01-12-2014
>
> Mathew|  12-01-2014
>
> Jack |   2014-01-01

I accept these formats (dd-mm-yy, mm-dd-yy, yy-mm-dd) in to the Date field,I used DATE_TIME it returned NULL and unable to use STR_TO_TIME because the column has different format.how can i use where and select clause on the Date Column.

Comment: It's a really, really good idea to always store the date information in the database in a normalized format -- preferably as a DATE or DATETIME type so you can use all the awesome SQL functions and have performant queries. This means you can accept a variety of flavors of dates during input but convert them all on the way into the database...

Comment: If you use `VARCHAR` then you need to use `DATE_FORMAT` to format all date into one type(like.. mm-dd-yy), but that should need one extra column in your table. So, use the standard data-type (`DATE` or `DATETIME`)

Comment: @RobP the insert,update query is generated dynamically so i cant identify the date fields.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to have uniform format for date. But in case it is not possible then need to add one more column detailing the format of the date column and handle the logic in application or format function:

```
Name | Date  | DateFormat

John | 2014-01-01  |yyyy-mm-dd

Kane | 01-12-2014  |dd-mm-yyyy

Mathew| 12-01-2014 |mm-dd-yyyy

Jack | 2014-01-01  |yyyy-mm-dd
```